# How to find the element type of an array in .net

Tags: .net, arrays, reflection, types, element

having a Type instance of an array,
e.g.:

```
var type = typeof(Guid[]);
if (type.IsArray)
{
    var elementType = type.????
}
```

I was looking in the Intellisense info, but didn't find anything useful, maybe I have just overlooked it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var elementType = type.GetElementType();
```

Comment: xiexie! thats what i was looking for

Comment: Bu xie ba, Sebastian, dan zheli ni bushi zai zhongguo ba !